# cycle through list, change style every x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple slideshow (jQuery Cycle) that displays an image every ten seconds (7 total images). In an adjacent div, I have a list with 7 bullet points. What's the easiest way to script a method in which the css/style of the appropriate bullet point changes as its accompanying image. The idea is to have all list items displayed, but 1 highlighted every 10 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Why not have `<span id="adjacentDivId_comment"> comment </span>` and then when its adjacent div is focused on, `document.getElementById(div.id+"_comment").setAttribute("class","hilited_Comment");`

Answer (score 0):

if I'm reading this correctly, I need a separate div for each comment? As it is, I have a div containing a ul composed of 7 li.